# Select siblings but without something in between

Tags: python, css, xpath, beautifulsoup

Here's one tricky scenario:

```css
#target ~ p {
  background: green;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="target">Title</h1>
<span>Some description</span>
<p>Yes</p>
<p>Yes</p>

<h1>Another Title</h1>
<span>Some description</span>
<p>No</p>
<p>No</p>
```

Does xpath allow selecting siblings but stop at a point? I would like to select the two `<p>`s under the first `<h1>` but not the ones under the second `<h1>`. Modifying the HTML is not possible as I am doing some web scraping and I am looking for a quick and dirty way of extracting data from paragraphs under a certain heading:

```
paragraphs = target.select("~ p")
```

Comment: Your query is not clear "I would like to select the two `<p>`s under the first `<h1>` but ones under the second `<h1>`".

Comment: @chriskirknielsen Typo. It should say "but not the ones". Basically, only the ones that say "Yes" in the example should be selected.

Comment: are you sure it contains no parent div, so it could be easier to target?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a "previous sibling" CSS selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817792/is-there-a-previous-sibling-css-selector)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```css
#target ~ p:not(:nth-last-of-type(-n+2)) {
  background: green;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="target">Title</h1>
<span>Some description</span>
<p>Yes</p>
<p>Yes</p>

<h1>Another Title</h1>
<span>Some description</span>
<p>No</p>
<p>No</p>
```

Or

```css
#target + span + p,
#target + span + p + p {
  background: green;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="target">Title</h1>
<span>Some description</span>
<p>Yes</p>
<p>Yes</p>

<h1>Another Title</h1>
<span>Some description</span>
<p>No</p>
<p>No</p>
```

Or

```css
#target ~ p:nth-of-type(1),
#target ~ p:nth-of-type(2) {
  background: green;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="target">Title</h1>
<span>Some description</span>
<p>Yes</p>
<p>Yes</p>

<h1>Another Title</h1>
<span>Some description</span>
<p>No</p>
<p>No</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use below XPath expression to get required paragraphs:

```
//h1/following-sibling::p[count(preceding-sibling::h1)=1]
```

If you know text of each `h1`, then you also can try:

```
//h1[.="Title"]/following-sibling::p[following-sibling::h1[.="Another Title"]]
```